# Return custom response with mitmproxy

Tags: mitmproxy

I'm trying to return custom response when using mitmproxy with the following code

```
from libmproxy.models import HTTPResponse
from netlib.http import Headers

def request(context, flow):
    if flow.request.pretty_url.endswith("example.com/index.php"):
        resp = HTTPResponse(
            [1, 1], 200, "OK",
            Headers(Content_Type="text/html"),
            "<html><body>hello world</body></html>")
        flow.reply(resp)
```

But the result is not as expected, in browser it shows up with http status codes, headers och body as clear text

```
[1,1] 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body>hello world</body></html>
```

how can i return it as actual "http" response so that chrome render it as html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't set http version as the example. Replace [1, 1] with "HTTP/1.1"

```py
from libmproxy.models import HTTPResponse
from netlib.http import Headers

def request(context, flow):
    if flow.request.pretty_url.endswith("example.com/index.php"):
        resp = HTTPResponse(
            "HTTP/1.1", 200, "OK",
            Headers(Content_Type="text/html"),
            "<html><body>hello world</body></html>")
        flow.reply(resp)
```

Comment: Can anyone update this example? I believe it's a bit outdated.

Comment: @xliiv, yea the answer is outdated as per 2022, you can go here https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-examples/#http-reply-from-proxy. No need import the `netlib` also.

Answer (score 7):

The snippet should looks like this

```
from mitmproxy import http


def request(flow):
    if flow.request.pretty_url.endswith("example.com/index.php"):
        flow.response = http.HTTPResponse.make(
            200,
            "<html><body>hello world</body></html>",
            {"content-type":"text/html"},
        )
```

for the newer versions of `mitmproxy`.

Comment: Here's a link to the example on Github: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/addons/http-reply-from-proxy.py

Answer (score 0):

You can also catch the response and edit/replace it as well.

Using BeautifulSoup also makes things easier.

My solution was to create an html file `replace.html` and replacing it with the original response:

```
import mitmproxy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def response(flow):
    if flow.request.pretty_host.endswith("example.com/index.php"):
        soup.BeautifulSoup(open("replace.html"))
        flow.response.content = str(soup).encode("utf8")
```

Comment: While this doesn't seem necessary for the question, but this is super useful if you want to "modify" responses.

Answer (score 0):

- Mitmproxy: 10.2.4
- Python:    3.10.12

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78241504/859837) for adding cookies to the response.

```py
from mitmproxy import http, flow

def request(flow: flow):
    headers = [
        (b'set-cookie', b'name1=value1'),
        (b'set-cookie', b'name2=value2'),
        (b'content-type', b'text/html'),
    ]
    flow.response = http.Response.make(200, b'<html>my content</html>', headers)
```

You can also call encode() method, like so `'set-cookie'.encode('utf-8')`, instead of `b'set-cookie'`. This is useful when iterating over a list/dict for building up your headers list of tuples.

Sending dict headers, like so `{"content-type":"text/html"}`, will work as long as you don't need to set multiple values of the same key. `set-cookie` is such an example that can't be done with dict unless you wanna set only one cookie.